# Trouble building Ogre on OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: osx, macos-snowleopard, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble building ogre (and therefore rviz) with ROS Electric on OSX Snow Leopard (10.6.8) with Homebrew. I've followed the ROS on OSX directions at http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew

I have checked out the visualization_common-1.6.2 tag of visualization_common, as that seems to be the current version supported with electric.

I get this error when building, followed by a bunch of "FOO has not been declared" that I assume come from this missing header.

```
In file included from /Users/hendrix/ros/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/PlugIns/CgProgramManager/include/OgreCgFxScriptLoader.h:35,
                 from /Users/hendrix/ros/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/PlugIns/CgProgramManager/src/OgreCgFxScriptLoader.cpp:29:
/Users/hendrix/ros/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/PlugIns/CgProgramManager/include/OgreCgPrerequisites.h:32:19: error: Cg/cg.h: No such file or directory
```

And eventually, the usual:

```
make[1]: *** [installed_osx] Error 1
BUILD FAILED: Plugin_CgProgramManager.dylib not created.   Is nvidia-cg-toolkit installed correctly?
make: *** [ogre] Error 1
```

`rosdep install ogre` claims that it has successfully installed the nvidia-cg-toolkit.

`sudo find / -iname cg.h` only finds:

`/Library/Frameworks/Cg.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers/cg.h`

Does anyone know if the newer versions of visualization_common (for Fuerte) are compatible with ROS Electric, and if they will solve this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27830/trouble-building-ogre-on-osx-snow-leopard/) by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As it turns out, the ogre build scripts weren't able to find the Cg framework during the build process.

The Cg installer put Cg.framework in /Library/Frameworks, but the orge build was looking in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks

I fixed this by creating a symlink in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks to /Library/Frameworks/Cg.framework

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1